# ROW_Number with Custom Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, rank, partition, row-number

I am trying to have `row_number` based on custom grouping but I am not able to produce it.

**Below is my Query**

```
CREATE TABLE mytbl (wid INT, id INT)
INSERT INTO mytbl Values(1,1),(2,1),(3,0),(4,2),(5,3)
```

Current Output

```
wid     id
1        1
2        1
3        0
4        2
5        3
```

**Query**

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY wid, CASE WHEN id = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY ID)
FROM mytbl
```

I would like to rank the rows based on custom condition like if ID is 0 then I have start new group until I have non 0 ID.

**Expected Output**

```
wid     id  RN
1        1  1
2        1  1
3        0  1
4        2  2
5        3  2
```

Comment: What do you mean *"until I have same rank."*? More than a single example of `0` would make this easier for us to understand the bigger picture. Or is it simply the number of `0` on all **prior** rows +1?

Comment: @Larnu I have updated it. Actually, I want rank the rows based on ID column, If any 0 value comes then I have to increment it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guessing here, as we don't have much clarification, but perhaps this:

```
SELECT wid,
       id,
       COUNT(CASE id WHEN 0 THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY wid ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) +1 AS [Rank]
FROM mytbl ;
```

Comment: The syntax is quite specific on this one, @VigneshKumarA. First you have a `COUNT` of values where the value is `0` for `id`. Due to the `ROWS BETWEEN` in the `OVER` clause, however, only rows **prior** to the row are counted. Then it adds 1 (as otherwise it would be a `0` ranking, not a `1` ranking).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you may use the next approach. Note, that you need to have an ordering column (I assume this is `wid` column):

Statement:

```
;WITH ChangesCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE WHEN LAG(id) OVER (ORDER BY wid) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS ChangeIndex
    FROM mytbl
), GroupsCTE AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(ChangeIndex) OVER (ORDER BY wid) AS GroupIndex
    FROM ChangesCTE
)
SELECT 
    wid,
    id,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY GroupIndex) AS Rank
FROM GroupsCTE
```

Result:

```
wid id  Rank
1   1   1
2   1   1
3   0   1
4   2   2
5   3   2
```

Answer (score 1):

without much clarification on the logic required, my understanding is you want to increase the `Rank` by 1 whenever `id = 0`

```
select  wid, id, 
        [Rank]  = sum(case when id = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by wid) 
                + case when id <> 0 then 1 else 0 end
from    mytbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
CREATE TABLE #mytbl (wid INT, id INT)
INSERT INTO #mytbl Values(1,1),(2,1),(3,0)
,(4,2),(5,3),(6,0),(7,4),(8,5),(9,6)

;with CTE as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by wid)rn 
from #mytbl where id=0

)
,CTE1 as
(
select max(rn)+1 ExtraRN from CTE
)
select a.* ,isnull(ca.rn,ca1.ExtraRN) from #mytbl a
outer apply(select top 1 * from CTE b 
where a.wid<=b.wid )ca
cross apply(select ExtraRN from CTE1)ca1


drop table #mytbl
```

Here both `OUTER APPLY` and `CROSS APPLY` will not increase `cardianility` estimate.It will always return only one rows.